# Insert a null value to an int column in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a subroutine to insert a record to sql server table.
The code:

```
    public void Insert_Met(int Counts, char Gender)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("@Counts", Counts);
        parameters.Add("@Gender", Gender);
        // run a stored procedure ExecuteNonQuery
    }
```

I other line code,

```
      int counts = Convert.ToInt32(numberUpdowncontrol1.Text);
       // from a control, maybe empty then it is null.
      Insert_Met(counts,'M');
```

My question is sometimes Counts can be null, so how to change my code?

Thanks,

Comment: Your "other line code" is not valid - you should show **real code**, as it helps us work with you better.

Comment: Do you *really* have a `Text` property which is assignable to an `int` variable?

Comment: @Jon, it is a numericupdown control in windows form. I feel that it is hard to assign a text to an int variable. How to change it?

Comment: @Love: For one thing, don't post code which doesn't compile... but then I'd use the `Value` property, which returns a `decimal`. You can then convert that to an integer just by casting, if you're certain that it won't lose any important information. Note that it still won't be null...

Comment: @Love I edited my post to include one option which checks for whether the user's set the control to empty (hit delete) but also does the cast to integer values for you...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `int? counts` instead of `int counts`, and check the value within your method:

```
public void InsertMet(int? counts, char gender)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("@Counts", counts.HasValue ? counts.Value : (object)DBNull.Value);
    parameters.Add("@Gender", gender);
    // run a stored procedure ExecuteNonQuery
}
```

---

> it is a numericupdown control in windows form. I feel that it is hard to assign a text to an int variable. How to change it?

In order to set the count value appropriately for the above, you could do:

```
int value = (int)numberUpdowncontrol1.Value;
int? counts = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(numberUpdowncontrol1.Text) ? value : (int?)null;

InsertMet(counts, 'M');
```

Comment: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.DBNull'. Please correct this error.

Comment: @Love that should do it - sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Following statement will always produce not null value

```
int counts = Convert.ToInt32(null); // Result is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = !(count == 0)? count ? (object)DBNull.Value
```

-If, count is not zero save the count value to database
-If it is zero save