# Passing NULL values in a query string

Tags: c#, sql, database, dbnull

I have a function called "InsertEmpolyee" that receives parameters to fill a query string. The thing is, I want to make some of these variables optional, in other words, I would like to be able to call the function without passing values to those parameters and still make the correct query string by inserting NULL into the database.

This is the function InsertEmployee

```
public int InsertEmployee(string FirstName, char Minit, string LastName, int SSN
 , int? Salary)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO Employee (Fname, Minit, Lname, SSN, Salary) " +    "Values ('" + FirstName + "','" + Minit + "','" + LastName + "'," + Salary + ");";
    return model.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
}
```

And here is how I call it.

```
int res = Controlobj.InsertEmployee(txtbox_FirstName.Text, txtbox_Minit.Text[0],
                   txtbox_LastName.Text, Int32.Parse(txtbox_SSN.Text), null);
```

I have tried to do the following

```
if (!Salary.HasValue)
            Salary = DBNull.Value;
```

But it gives me the following error "Can't implicitly convert system.DBNull to int?"

How can I fix this? And is there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Do not use string concatenation for your queries, use parameterized queries instead. This will ensure your code is not vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It will also solve your problem because you can then pass in `System.DBNull.Value` as the parameter value when one of your incoming parameters is `null`.

Comment: Is `model` an instance of a `SqlCommand` ?

Comment: @Igor No, it's a class I have written. I will read about parameterized queries. Actually I knew that string concatenation is vulnerable for SQL injections, but this is literally my first time dealing databases.

Comment: Cast DBNull.Value to object: (object)DBNull.Value

Comment: Why recreate `SqlCommand`? If you want to abstract it then use `DbCommand` or `IDbCommand` which are already abstracted types. You are stripping away core functionality that *you need*. See [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @YpsilonIV I have also tried that, it gives the same error but regarding type "object" instead of "int?", I have also tried casting to "object?" with the same results.

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018939/insert-a-null-value-to-an-int-column-in-sql-server should work for you

Comment: Again, you *need to use parameters*. The *initial* suggested solution by @YpsilonIV is wrong and can't work in this manner. Learn how to use parameters, it is not that difficult to do.

Comment: @Igor Yes I will. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code doesn't only fail on `null`, but on strings containing apostrophes. There could be other pitfalls as well. That's why we use parameters.

```
public int InsertEmployee(string Fname, char Minit, string Lname, int SSN, int? Salary)
{
    return model.ExecuteNonQuery(
        @"
            INSERT INTO Employee (
                       Fname, Minit, Lname, SSN, Salary
                   ) VALUES (
                       @Fname, @Minit, @Lname, @SSN, @Salary
                   )
        ",
        new SqlParameter("@Fname",  SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = (object)Fname  ?? System.DBNull.Value },
        new SqlParameter("@Minit",  SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value =         Minit                         },
        new SqlParameter("@Lname",  SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = (object)Lname  ?? System.DBNull.Value },
        new SqlParameter("@SSN",    SqlDbType.Int    ) { Value =         SSN                           },
        new SqlParameter("@Salary", SqlDbType.Int    ) { Value = (object)Salary ?? System.DBNull.Value });
}
```

Comment: This is not a constructor of `SqlParameter` that you should be using. It can cause very confusing behaviour because it infers the type from the value passed in, but the value passed in may be `null`, which doesn't have any type. (BTW, the link I included earlier was not a good one, please ignore that, now edited out.)

Comment: I have written the model class myself, and thus the function ExecuteNonQuery takes a string as a parameter. What would be the suitable parameter for your proposed method?

Comment: Then you need to fix ExecuteNonQuery. There's a reason SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery takes parameters.

Comment: @hvd, Addressed.

Comment: Looks good to me. You could alternatively have kept it inline with `new SqlParameter(...) { Value = ... }` but a separate method is of course perfectly fine as well.

Comment: @hvd, Awesome! :) I was not aware of that. Answer updated.

Comment: The "Value = (object)Fname  ?? System.DBNull.Value" part produces an error that says "Can't convert from System.Data.SqlClinet.SqlParameter to string". Any idea what's the problem?